# jQuery validation plugin conditional check if either input have value or select dropdown selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

So i am making some form with price and user is allowed either to select one of options from dropdown select box or either to put his own price in input value.
He don't need both values but i would like to check if either of those 2 values is not meet and display error using jquery validation plugin.

So here is the form.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <label  for="price">Price</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">€</div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" placeholder="0" data-error="Please insert price for your item" required value="">
                </div>

                <strong class="text-center"> <?php _e('or') ?> </strong>

                <select class="form-control" id="conditional_price" name="conditional_price" placeholder="Select">
                <option value="" <?php echo $conditional_price == '' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Select</option>
                <option value="1" <?php echo $conditional_price == '1' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Free</option>
                <option value="2" <?php echo $conditional_price == '2' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Deal</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="price" class="validation-error-message text-danger"></label>
            <label for="conditional_price" class="validation-error-message text-danger"></label>
</div>
```

I have tried various options but nothing works, this is what partially works so far

```
    rules: {
        offers: 'required',
        title: 'required',
        price: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $("#conditional_price").is(':empty');
            }
        },
        conditional_price: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $("#price").is(':empty');
            }
        }

    },
```

So on clicking submit button we should check if either of those two is valid. If user put the price than continue, if user put select than continue, but if none of those two is filled (if user don't put price and also don't select anything) to show error to either put price or select from dropdown.

Comment: [Please refer to the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/blank-selector/).  It is not `:empty`, it's `:blank`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct except one thing. You are using select and `is(":empty")` with select will always return false. You can use this.

```
rules: {
        offers: 'required',
        title: 'required',
        price: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $("#conditional_price").val() == "";
            }
        },
        conditional_price: {
            required: function(element) {
                return $("#price").val() == "";
            }
        }

    },
```

`$("#conditional_price").val() == ""` will return true when the first option(with value="") is selected.

Comment: This doesn't completely work, however return $("#price").val() == ""; does work so this solves my problem. Now just if i can figure out to have one error message for both fields. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks for edit. :) @AleksandarĐorđević

Comment: Please note that `:empty` is not the correct selector, and `.is(':blank')` would have worked just fine.  https://jqueryvalidation.org/blank-selector/